# APC SmartUPS suddenly all lights flashing. What's going on?

Tags: ups, apc, apc-smart-ups, nut

upsfault: I have a APC SmartUPS 2U 1500 somewhere in a rack far away. Batteries were replaced recently and UPS was working without issues for a long time.

Suddenly yesterday, the entire equipment attached to the UPS was off. I send someone there to see what's going on and **all lights** in front of the UPS were **flashing**. It did not beep.

According to the manual, a constant lit and beep would indicate a UPS fault. Furthermore, "Front Panel LEDs Flash Sequentially" would indicate that the UPS has been shut down remotely and will return when utility power returns. But it was not shut down and utility power never went out.

I told the person to push the off button. While this should turn off the UPS, it started the fan.
Then I told the person to push the on button. Now all connected devices powered up again but the relay sound is constantly audible.

I cannot connect to the UPS over USB (I use nut and I only get `error: Driver not connected`). It used to work.

What does that mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

It is telling you to RTFM and contact the manufacturer. Likely something with the batteries is wrong. That the batteries are new is "irrelevant" - they may well NOW be defective due to a production error.

Alternatively it basically blew the hardware.

What to do? STANDARD BUSINESS PRACTICE:

- Replace the UPS with the spare you have for cases like that (because having spares for critical equipment = Standard Operating Practice)
- Have UPS analyzed, possibly by manufacturer.

In MY case I would also:

- Order ANOTHER space as the UPS once fixed is NOT going back into a remove location but stays is either staying as low priority thingy OR being sold on Ebay.